# Deletes Slow on a Oracle BIG Table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which has around 180 million records and 40 indexes. A nightly program, loads data into this table but due to certain business conditions we can only delete and load data into this table. The nightly program will bring new records or updates to existing records in the table from the source system.We have limited window i.e about 6 hours to complete the extract from the source system, perform business transformations and finally load the data into this target table and be ready for users to consume the data in the morning. The issue which we are facing is that the delete from this table takes a lot of time mainly due to the 40 indexes on the table(an average of 70000 deletes per hour). I did some digging on the internet and see the below options

a) **Drop or disable indexes before delete and then rebuild indexes:** The program which loads data into the target table after delete and loading the data needs to perform quite a few updates for which the indexes are critical. And to rebuild 1 index it takes almost 1.5 hours due to the enormous amount of data in the table. So this approach is not feasible due to the time it takes to rebuild indexes and due to the limited time we have to get the data ready for the users

b) **Use bulk delete:** Currently the program deletes based on rowid and deletes records one by one as below

`DELETE
           FROM <table>
          WHERE rowid = g_wpk_tab(ln_i);`

g_wpk_tab is the collection which holds rowids to be deleted which is read by looping via FOR ALL and I do an intermediate commit every 50000 row deletes.

Tom of AskTom says in this discussion over here says that the bulk delete and row by row delete will take almost the same amount of time

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5033906925164

So this wont be a feasible option as well

c)**Regular Delete:** Tom of AskTom suggests to use the regular delete and even that takes a long time probably due to the number of indexes on this table

d)**CTAS:** This approach is out of question because the program needs to recreate the table , create the 40 indexes and then proceed with the updates and I mentioned above an index will take atleast 1.5 hrs to create

If you could provide me any other suggestions I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** As of now we have decided to go with the approach suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jonearles to archive instead of delete. Approach is to add a flag to the table to mark the records to be deleted as DELETE and then have a post delete program run during the day to delete off the records. This will ensure that the data is available for users at the right time. Since users consume via OBIEE we are planning to set content level filter on the table to not look at the archival column so that users needn't know about what to select and what to ignore.

Comment: For using `for all` do you mean you're bulk collecting rowids and using `forall`..? Do you have Enterprise Edition and can you partition your table? Does the table need to be so big in the first place? Have you considered making it smaller? Do you need 40 indexes? If you remove 10 it'll make your deletes quicker. It sounds as though you've put an entire database in one table... if you had one small process deleting a few old records 24 hours a day would that make much difference?

Comment: Can you run 20 processes in parallel in order to speed up the delete? You could use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE to split the operation and start 20 easily enough. Have you traced the slowness to any particular cause; for instance if the entire table is on one disk and you have 20-30 processes trying to delete from the same disk you may get massive I/O problems. If you have multiple processes trying to delete rowids from the same blocks you'll get contentions. Lastly, what disks are you using? Are they 15 year old 5rpm spinning disks or are they lovely new £9k/TB SANs?

Comment: I am using for all to loop through the collection which has the rowids. I am not using bulk collect. I was told that the Partition costs a lot and the client wont be able to afford that. The table contains the invoice transactions of the company at a detail level for the last 4 fiscal years. We are looking at whether we can remove some indexes. I have already started trying out by dropping some indexes and see what is the performance gain.

Comment: I cant have a process to delete 24 hours a day as i need to reinsert the records which I delete with the latest updates ( as there would have been updates during the business day and since the table has different types of transactions from different types of sources I don't have a unique key to merge data into the table)

Comment: 40 indexes!  wow, thats gonna hurt.  what is the logic for the deletes? (and how many rows deleted per day on average?)

Comment: I will surely try DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. We haven't tried to trace the slowness to see whats causing it and I have no idea on the hardware being used. Need to desperately get the DBAs to look at this.

Comment: Oh yeah. We are on 10g so cant use the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE

Comment: @tbone deletes are based on if a transaction gets an update in the source system delete the transaction and reinsert with the updated data.Since the table contains data from different source systems there is no unique key by which I can do a merge. At an average we expect around 100k records daily for deletes.

Comment: Shaz can you [edit] your question with updates and delete your comments; it keeps things a lot cleaner. Even if you can't use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE you can still manually chunk on the mod() of the ascii() of something that does it will to run more than one process at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parallel DML**  `alter session enable parallel dml;`, `delete /*+ parallel */ ...;`, `commit;`.  Sometimes it's that easy.

**Parallel DDL**  `alter index your_index rebuild nologging compress parallel;`.  NOLOGGING to reduce the amount of redo generated during the index rebuild.  COMPRESS can significantly reduce the size of a non-unique index, which significantly reduces the rebuild time.  PARALLEL can also make a huge difference in rebuild time if you have more than one CPU or more than one disk.  If you're not already using these options, I wouldn't be surprised if using all of them together improves index rebuilds by an order of magnitude.  And then 1.5 * 40 / 10 = 6 hours.

**Re-evaluate your indexes**  Do you *really* need 40 indexes?  It's entirely possible, but many indexes are only created because "indexes are magic".  Make sure there's a legitimate reason behind each index.  This can be very difficult to do, very few people document the reason for an index.  Before you ask around, you may want to gather some information.  Turn on [index monitoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_1010.htm#SQLRF52784) to see which indexes are really being used.  And even if the index is used, see how it is used, perhaps through v$sql_plan.  It's possible that an index is used for a specific statement but another index would have worked just as well.

**Archive instead of delete**  Instead of deleting, just set a flag to mark a row as archived, invalid, deleted, etc.  This will avoid the immediate overhead of index maintenance.  Ignore the rows temporarily and let some other job delete them later.  The large downside to this is that it affects any query on the table.

Upgrading is probably out of the question, but 12c has an interesting new feature called [in-database archiving](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17613/part_lifecycle.htm#CHDDAIDE).  It's a more transparent way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: for option 1 i.e. parallel DML, would that be a real option if the program were to use the same table in any SQL statement after the parallel DML operation statement (in this case delete)? Specifically - "If any DML statement in a transaction modifies a table in parallel, no subsequent serial or parallel query or DML statement can access the same table again in that transaction. This means that the results of parallel modifications cannot be seen during the transaction." unless there is an intermediate commit.

Comment: @Annjawn Yes, there are many limitations and side-effects of parallelism.  But if the process was going to have the data offline anyway there are usually workarounds to those issues.  I'll add a `commit;` to my steps since that's almost always the next step, unless there is an error.

Comment: I have faced this numerous times with many program that we have here which perform bulk DMLs on pretty large tables and this is always the problem that restricts using parallel DML. `commit;` is not an option because the program may fail after the commit point, potentially leaving us with corrupt data and even difficult to recover the job failure.

Comment: @Annjawn It's difficult to combine long transactions with massive DML.  In my experience, that kind of work is usually done with staging tables.  If all goes well, the final staging table is put into production (with a partition exchange, synonym swap, etc.)  If something fails, the process stops and someone has to manually examine it tomorrow, but the final production data has not been touched.  This requires extra structures, storage, and processes.  In many cases it's worth it if the process runs 10 times faster.  But you're right, in many cases the first option will not work for people.